# Can I take friends flying with a private pilot glider license?

Tags: usa, pilot-certification, glider

In the US, will glider clubs let you take up friends in a two-seater if you have a private license? Or do you need a commercial license?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Glider PPL will suffice, did it yesterday and three or four times in the past three months.

That's me in the back seat preparing to take a co-worker for her first glider ride in a [Grob-103](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grob_G103a_Twin_II):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In general, YES.

However, different clubs have different rules, so you will want to check with a given club.